# Route from node-js app engine to google cloud functions - integration of cloud functions with App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, routes, cloud, google-cloud-functions

I have a NodeJS web application running in Google App Engine. Also I've mapped my custom domain to it, say `example.com`.

I've few business functions (microservices) written in node.js and deployed as google cloud functions to the same Google Project.

I want to have a routing defined for the cloud functions (say, `function1`, `function2`).

All requests coming for `example.com/ms/fun1/*` should go to `function1` and all requests coming for `example.com/ms/fun2/*` should go to `function2`.

I've checked the [`dispatch.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#creating_a_dispatch_file) configuration in App Engine, but that seems to be defined only for the services defined inside App Engine.

Kindly help me achieve the above required behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As you observed, the `dispatch.yaml` file can only be used to route to a certain GAE service, not to CFs. There is no other Google-supplied mechanism for achieving what you want.

But inside your GAE app you can register handlers for those URLs which would simply trigger the respective CFs (invoke their real URLs) - exactly what you desire. But you might not be able to take advantage of the potentially longer [CF timeouts](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) - the GAE ones can be shorter in some cases, depending on environment and/or scalability configs and their requirements would have to be satisfied in this case.

If you're expecting the CFs to be called rather often this approach may also be a bit cost-inefficient, in the sense that CFs are generally more expensive than GAE (being charged for every invocation as opposed to GAE being charged by instance uptime, regardless how many invocations it handles) - it may be cheaper to just execute the respective functionality inside your GAE handler, maybe even re-package those CFs as GAE services instead.